# Executing a PowerShell script and leaving it running

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script that, once executed listens on a port. I want to execute this script and leave it running while the C# program continues to run.

Here is what I have right now but when it gets to this line it waits until the script is finished (which it never does).

```
Process proc = Process.Start("powershell.exe", @"/K tcdrvrcunit.exe Automation.txt");
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
```

Comment: If you're wanting to not lock up the main thread you'll have to run the script on a separate thread. You can do this using Jobs in Powershell or using multithreading.

Comment: what do you mean by leave it running? do you want to leave the processID to be run permanently for the PSScript?

Comment: subscribe to the `Process.Exited` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) if you don't want to block

Comment: `/K` is a parameter for `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell.

Comment: Don't `WaitForExit()` if you don't want to wait for (the process to) exit.

Comment: @RanadipDutta I want to execute the script and leave the window opened while the program continues to run.
This is because I need the listener to pick up on a request I make later on in the program